# How to use std::atomic or boost::atomic with the classic compiler?

Tags: c++, c++builder

I'm currently working on a mid-sized project in C++ Builder 10.1.2 where I am unfortunately tied to the BCC32 *classic* compiler (mainly for reliability and speed reasons).

For some background parsing, it would be nice if I could use *C++11*'s `std::atomic`, but the *classic* compiler is not capable of that. Even `boost::atomic` is not available, because only *boost* V.1.39 can be installed for BCC32, which comes with no `boost::atomic` built-in.

So...

- Is there some possibility to use a newer *boost* version with the *classic* compiler?
- Are there some alternatives to `... ::atomic` (except for mutex-wrapped *normal* variables)?

Comment: Why would you think an 11 year-old compiler would be more reliable and faster than a current one?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or **other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: @Captain I don't think OP is asking for a library recommendation though. What made you think that?

Comment: @Rakete1111 `...alternatives to...` seems pretty clearly under "library or tool" to me.

Comment: @Mark OP included an alternative (mutext-wrapped normal variables) so I don't think OP wants libraries, but ways to replicate `std::atomic`

Comment: Well, then check how it is implemented in boost, and implement it on your own for bcc32 in a similar manner. It is not likely that any existing library will support such an old compiler.

Comment: Sorry for my unclear question: Yes, I'd like to know ways to implement that atomic myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement lock-less `std::atomic` yourself, provided you have access to assembly. Just figure out the corresponding assembly instructions for your CPU and code them. Easy way of doing this would be to compile some test code with `std::atomic` using modern compiler on your CPU and look into generated ASM. Of course, it would be CPU-dependent and you will use portability.

If your compiler doesn't allow you to use ASM or you do not want to marry yourself to particular CPU, you can rely on OS-provided API - both *nix and Windows has family of atomic functions.